# POST- запрос к FCM для отправки push из андроид-приложения другому пользователю

Tags: android, post, запрос, push-уведомления, fcm

Я новичок в андроид разработке. Создал свой чат с использованием Firebase. Подключил FCM и могу теперь отправлять push уведомления из консоли. Естественно я хочу отправлять пуши при отправке новых сообщений в чат, то есть по нажатию кнопки в моем приложении, а не из консоли. Спустя месяц поисков и чуть не уйдя в изучение разработки собственного сервера на PHP , я наконец выяснил , что можно отправлять пуши простым POST запросом к API FCM (в запросах к серверу я тоже новичок). Найдя здесь только один ответ, на его основе я все-таки составил этот POST запрос при помощи okHTTP. Но к сожалению пуш уведомление все равно не приходит. Если кто-то может подсказать в чем причина, или помочь составить грамотный работающий POST запрос к API FCM для отправки пуша к конкретному девайсу , чей токен я могу получить , буду очень благодарен. Потому что я замучался штудировать темы уводящие меня в сторону. Спасибо.
Вот мой код в MainActivity  для отправки запроса

```
public   Call post(String url, String json, Callback callback) {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization","key=AA...cK") // мой ключ авторизации
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(callback);
        return call;
    }
```

далее

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    public  void otprPush()  {



        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
            param.put("Hii", "there");
            param.put("Hours", "16:00");
            jsonObject.put("data", param);
            jsonObject.put("title", "news");
            jsonObject.put("text", "newsText");
            jsonObject.put("click_action", "test");
            //jsonObject.put("", "test");
            jsonObject.put("to", "cW...CB1z");   //здесь токен девайса, который я получил вот так FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() один раз , вывел в EditText скопировал, и в ствавил строку сюда

                                                           
                                       
            post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", jsonObject.toString(), new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            //Something went wrong
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                String responseStr = response.body().string();
                                Log.d("Response1", responseStr);
                             //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"запрос ушел", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                // Do what you want to do with the response.
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"не пошло", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Log.d("Exception", "JSON exception", ex);
        }

    }
```

потом вызываю метод otprPush() по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: И что происходит, когда вы вызываете ваш метод отправки? Наверное ошибка какая-то? Если да - то какая?

Comment: Вот именно, что нету ошибки явной , приложение не падает, там у меня в коде вывод в Log прописан   if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                String responseStr = response.body().string();
                                Log.d("Response1", responseStr); Так вот этот лог выводится при нажатии на кнопку отправки. Приложение падает , только если я хочу вывести в этом месте Toast , ну типа , что запрос отправлен.

Comment: Я просто даже не знаю как понять , работающий ли это запрос. дошел ли до FCM , или я фигню написал. Если он нормальный, то ну быть может я как-то неправильно получил токен девайса-цели. Или в теле json что-то не так указано. Я не шарю в этом если честно, казалось довольно простым дельцем)

Comment: Посмотрите что у вас в `responseStr` - там может быть описание проблемы, которая у вас возникла

Comment: 2021-02-01 23:55:25.871 32427-32719/com.example.testapp D/Response1: {"multicast_id":1569615198573516585,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1612212927360626%a635695ef9fd7ecd"}]}
вот такая вот штука

Comment: Судя по всему запрос успешно ушёл. Как вы определили, что данные не пришли? Вы отправляете data сообщение, оно не будет автоматически отображено в шторке. Будет только вызов метода в сервисе. Может в этом дело - вы не туда смотрите на предмет пришедшего пуша?

Comment: Хорошо, а как сделать , чтобы нотификейшн мгновенно отображался в шторке? Мне нужен самый что ни наесть простецкий пуш. Потому что с кансоли он выводится мгновенно. Да я открыл два эмулятора и в том , чей токен скопировал - закрыл приложение и жду уведомление в шторке.

Comment: По идее вам надо с запросом послать вот такой JSON: `{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Спасибо. А тогда такой вопрос, совсем для тупого, как правильно это джейсон в строку превратить?  Или нужно в json объект, ауже его потом при отправке в строку?  Я просто с этими миллионами скобок в json путаюсь, и просто взяв в ковычки ваше json тело, оно в стринг не превращается, естественно, а все ломается

Comment: Сложно дать однозначный ответ. Лично я взял бы либу специальную (Moshi или Gson) и ей бы нужный JSON получил бы из класса, который описывает желаемую структуру данных.